# Why doesn't my Hash function as intended?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am writing a TFIDF program - all of which should be okay, but I'm having a small (or large..) problem with the hashes working as intended.

To keep this short, the code at hand is:

```
#Word matrix is an array that contains hashes (obviously)
#i've done some stuff before this and these are working as expected
puts word_matrix[3][:yahoo] # => 2
puts word_matrix[100][:yahoo] # => 0
puts $total_words_hash[:yahoo] #=> 0 

#Essentially, this block is taking a hash of all the words (values = 0) and trying
#to run through them adding the only the values of the other hash to the temporary
#and then setting the temp to the old hash position (so that there are 0 values
#and the values occurring in that document.. yet, it assigns the same values to
#ALL of the hashes of word_matrix[]

#now we run this block and everything breaks down for some reason..
for i in 0...word_matrix.size
  tmp_complete_words_hash = $total_words_hash #all values should be zero...
  word_matrix[i].each do |key,val| #for each key in the hash we do this..
    tmp_complete_words_hash[key] = val
  end
  word_matrix[i] = tmp_complete_words_hash
end
puts word_matrix[3][:yahoo] # => 2
puts word_matrix[100][:yahoo] # => 2 -- THIS SHOULD BE 0 Still...
```

Could anyone shed any light as to why this is assigning the same values to ALL the hashes of the array? It is as if `tmp_complete_words_hash` is not being reset everytime.

Comment: Just as a FYI: global variables like `$total_words_hash` are usually the wrong thing and are seldom needed in correctly written code. Also using `for` in `for i in 0...word_matrix.size` is not idiomatic Ruby. Learn to iterate over your arrays using `each` and `map` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clone the hash.

```
tmp_complete_words_hash = $total_words_hash.clone
```

Otherwise, both variables are pointing to the same hash, and you're constantly modifying that hash.

In fact, most objects in Ruby are like this. Only a few (such as numerics, strings) aren't.

Try this in the IRB:

```
class MyClass
    attr_accessor :value
end

x = MyClass.new
y = x
x.value = "OK"
puts y.value
```

Comment: Thank's Jim! Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

> why this is assigning the same values to ALL the hashes of the array?

There is only one hash. You are assigning the same hash (the one pointed to by `$total_words_hash`) to every element in the array:

```
tmp_complete_words_hash = $total_words_hash
```

Here, you make `tmp_complete_words_hash` point to the same object as `$total_words_hash`

```
word_matrix[i] = tmp_complete_words_hash
```

And here you assign that hash to every element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a hash variable to another hash variable. It will reference the same memory location, if you change one hash, same will be reflected to another hash.

```
total_words_hash = {}
tmp_complete_words_hash = total_words_hash
1.9.3 (main):0 > total_words_hash.object_id
=> 85149660
1.9.3 (main):0 > tmp_complete_words_hash.object_id
=> 85149660
total_words_hash[:test] = 0
1.9.3 (main):0 > tmp_complete_words_hash
=> {
    :test => 0
}
1.9.3 (main):0 > tmp_complete_words_hash[:test_reverse] = 1
=> 1
1.9.3 (main):0 > tmp_complete_words_hash
=> {
      :test => 0,
      :test_reverse => 1
}
```

So you can create a duplicate hash for this purpose using hash method `dup`.

```
1.9.3 (main):0 > tmp_complete_words_hash = total_words_hash.dup
1.9.3 (main):0 > total_words_hash.object_id
=> 85149660
1.9.3 (main):0 > tmp_complete_words_hash.object_id
=> 97244920
```

In your case just use.

```
tmp_complete_words_hash = $total_words_hash.dup
```